# Pass php object to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I was wandering if it is possible to send a php object/array from a database into a javascript function through html?

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
<?php
$test = array('Apple', 'Banana', 'Lemon');
?>

<a href="javascript:;" onclick="myfuntion(<?php echo json_encode($test) ?>);">Send object</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myfuntion(test)
{
    console.log("What is first fruit: "+test[0]);
}
</script>
```

I get this error in my console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
myfuntion([
```

What am I missing? Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Change the line as `<a href="javascript:;" onclick="myfuntion('<?php echo json_encode($test) ?>');">Send object</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because string generated by `json_encode` contains double quotes and conflict with `onclick="..."`

Try to wrap it with `htmlspecialchars`

```php
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="myfuntion(<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($test)) ?>);">Send object</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid quotes collision just store your json as an object somewhere:

```
<?php
$test = array('Apple', 'Banana', 'Lemon');
?>

<a href="javascript:;" onclick="myfuntion();">Send object</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
var data = <?php echo json_encode($test) ?>;

function myfuntion()
{
    console.log("What is first fruit: "+data[0]);
}
</script>
```

Or using an argument:

```
<?php
$test = array('Apple', 'Banana', 'Lemon');
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var data = <?php echo json_encode($test) ?>;
</script>    
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="myfuntion(data);">Send object</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myfuntion(jsonObj)
{
    console.log("What is first fruit: "+jsonObj[0]);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing correct only thing missing is, you need to surround passed argument in parentheses as below.

```
<a href="javascript:;"
  onclick="myfuntion('<?php echo json_encode($test) ?>');">Send object</a>
```

Because your code will echo json encoded values/string in argument *(and string must be inside single of double quotes)* and function arguments must needs to be surrounded in parentheses. But if it is number then it will work but when you are dealing with objects and array you must need to enclose them in `''`.

And in your js code just parse that argument to `JSON` using `JSON.parse` method.

Comment: That would send JSON string instead of JS object :/

Comment: @Dipesh Parmar Well, changed what you suggested now this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token, myfunction('[

Comment: @u_mulder edited answer, but i was making point clear to him rather than writing all code for OP, as i mentioned it will be json encoded value/string so later all he need to do was parse it on js code.

Comment: Actually, just changed this <?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($test)) ?> as Anggara suggested, and it worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pass in function direct use $test array json in js like this.

```
<?php
$test = array('Apple', 'Banana', 'Lemon');
?>

<a href="javascript:;" onclick="myfuntion();">Send object</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myfuntion()
{
    var test = <?php echo json_encode($test); ?>;

    for(var i=0; i<test.length; i++){
    console.log("What is first fruit: "+test[i]);

    }

}
</script>
```

If you pass in a tag then it passes a string instead of json.

Hope this is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parentheses for PHP code inside myfuntion.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="myfuntion(<?php echo json_encode($test) ?>);">Send object</a>
```